# Returning Specific List Items In Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list, which contains the names of several text files, like this:

```
["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]
```

How can I check AND return these elements of the list, that start with "order_" or any other given sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> data = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]    
>>> [ x for x in data if x.startswith('order_')]
['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
```

#### Explanation:

A list comprehension typically looks something like:

```
[somefunction(x) for x in data if some_condition]
```

In our case, we only want to select items from data, not manipulate them.  So, `somefunction` is not needed and the expression simplifies to:

```
[x for x in data if some_condition]
```

In our case, the condition is that the string starts with `order_`.  Python has a handy string method to test just for this.  It is called, naturally enough, `startswith`.  So, the final form is:

```
[ x for x in data if x.startswith('order_')]
```

If you ever have need for it, there is an analogous string method to test the end of a string.  For example:

```
>>> [ x for x in data if x.endswith('txt')]
['catfile.txt', 'santa.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the list with [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
>>> lst = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]
>>> [x for x in lst if x.startswith('order_')]
['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
>>>
```

You can even make this an in-place operation by using `[:]`:

```
>>> lst = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]
>>> lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x.startswith('order_')]
>>> lst
['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
>>>
```

Finally, it should be noted that `str.startswith` allows you to specify a tuple of prefixes to search for:

```
>>> lst = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]
>>> [x for x in lst if x.startswith(('order_', 'cat'))]
['catfile.txt', 'order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [92]: L = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]

In [93]: answer = []

In [94]: for elem in L:
   ....:     if elem.startswith("order_"):
   ....:         answer.append(elem)
   ....:         

In [95]: answer
Out[95]: ['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
```

As a function:

```
In [96]: def returnOrders(L):
   ....:     answer = []
   ....:     for elem in L:
   ....:         if elem.startswith("order_"):
   ....:             answer.append(elem)
   ....:     return answer
   ....: 

In [97]: L
Out[97]: ['catfile.txt', 'order_2014_11_11_11', 'santa.txt', 'order_2013_10_20']

In [98]: returnOrders(L)
Out[98]: ['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
```

More generally:

```
In [99]: def returnStarters(L, prefix):
   ....:     answer = []
   ....:     for elem in L:
   ....:         if elem.startswith(prefix):
   ....:             answer.append(elem)
   ....:     return answer
   ....: 

In [100]: L
Out[100]: ['catfile.txt', 'order_2014_11_11_11', 'santa.txt', 'order_2013_10_20']

In [101]: returnStarters(L, "order_")
Out[101]: ['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
l1 = ["catfile.txt", "order_2014_11_11_11", "santa.txt", "order_2013_10_20"]
l2 = []

for i in l1:
    if i.startswith("order"):
        l2.append(i)
```

Samples and output

```
print l1
['catfile.txt', 'order_2014_11_11_11', 'santa.txt', 'order_2013_10_20']

print l2
['order_2014_11_11_11', 'order_2013_10_20']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
seq = "order_"
results = [item for item in list if item.startswith(seq)]
```

Comment: Oh wow, dumb mistake on my part, thanks, fixed. I was wondering why the downvotes appeared.

Comment: Submission time were almost same but your initial answer was totally different. You were using `in` not `.startswith()` in original answer, that update came way later.

Comment: Yes, I realized I misread the question, so I fixed my answer. What's the issue?